# Use Parameter to Return All, Matched, or Unmatched Rows from Left Joined Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a goal to return rows from a table's matches on a left joined table based off a parameter value. Here is an example of my code:

```
declare @SalesType varchar(10) = 'All'
    
select sales.* 
from sales
left join esales on sales.pk = esales.fk
```

- If the parameter is 'All', I want all Sales table rows to be returned
- If the parameter is 'No ESales', I want Sales table rows where esales.fk is null to be returned
- If the parameter is 'ESales', I want Sales table rows where esales.fk is not null to be returned

I have accomplished this by using the below:

```
declare @SalesType varchar(10) = 'All';

declare @SalesType_Table Table (id int not null);

insert into @SalesType_Table
select 1 
where @SalesType in ('All','No ESales');

insert into @SalesType_Table
select 2
where @SalesType in ('All','ESales');

    select sales.* 
    from sales
    left join esales on sales.pk = esales.fk
    where case when esales.fk is null then 1 
                when esales.fk is not null then 2 
                end 
            in (select id from @SalesType_Table)
```

However I feel this is clunky and there has to be a better way to accomplish this.  I am using a large table and a case statement on esales.fk is inefficient.  Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be the below with some basic boolean logic:

```
SELECT s.* --I advise against using * in a objet's definition and you should define your columns
       --Why is esales not in the SELECT?
FROM dbo.sales s
     LEFT JOIN s.esales es ON s.pk = es.fk
WHERE @YourParam = 'All'
   OR (@YourParam = 'No ESales' AND se.pk IS NULL)
   OR (@YOurParam = 'ESales' AND se.pk IS NOT NULL)
--ORDER BY Some Column
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is there, as the query could easily cache a  plan for one of the other scenarios which would be poor for a different one. Therefore the clause forces the instance to recreate the plan each time it's run.

Comment: So much faster.  Thank you!  I knew when I posted this there would be a much easier way that I was completely missing.   My sample query is nothing like the query I am actually running and I am not using *.  I appreciate including OPTION (RECOMPILE) in your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` and conditional logic in the `where`:

```
select s.* 
from sales s
where @SalesType = 'All' or
      (@SalesType = 'No Esales' and not exists (select 1 from esales e where e.fk = s.pk)) or
      (@SalesType = 'Esales' and exists (select 1 from esales e where e.fk = s.pk));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this where clause:

```
declare @SalesType varchar(10) = 'All'
    
select sales.* 
from sales
left join esales on sales.pk = esales.fk
where 
(@salesType = 'all'
 or @salesType = 'No ESales' and esales.fk is null
 or @salesType = 'ESales' and esales.fk is not null)
)
```